# Listener inside producer

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm trying to create `producer` for a listener.
My code looks like this

```
suspend fun foo() = produce{
    someEvent.addListener {
        this.send(it)
    }
}
```

But I'm getting error `Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine` which makes sense. My question is. Is there a way to implement this pattern using coroutines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to implement it, depending on what you are trying to achieve:

If you want to receive just *the most recent* event, then you should use a *conflated* channel and `offer` method that aways succeeds for it:

```
fun foo() = produce<T>(capacity = Channel.CONFLATED) {
    someEvent.addListener {
        offer(it)
    }
}
```

If it is critical to receive *all* events, then your choices depend on the behavior of your event producer. The key question to ponder here is what happens if your event producer starts producing lots of events "non-stop". Most "synchronous" event producers, as a rule of thumb, do not support an explicit back-pressure signal, but they still support an implicit back-pressure signal -- they will slow down if their listeners are slow or block the thread. So, usually, the following solution works perfectly for synchronous event producers:

```
fun foo() = produce<T>() {
    someEvent.addListener {
        runBlocking { send(it) }
    }
}
```

You can also specify some positive `capacity = xxx` as parameter to `produce` builder as a performance optimization if you have cases when a batch of events is produced at once and you don't want to block the producer, but let the consumer handle them at its own pace.

In the rare case when your producer does not understand an implicit blocking back-pressure signal (when it as some sort of multi-threaded contraption violently producing events without internal synchronization), then you can use channel with unlimited capacity with `offer`, but beware that you risk running out memory if the producer outruns the consumer:

```
fun foo() = produce<T>(capacity = Channel.UNLIMITED) {
    someEvent.addListener {
        offer(it)
    }
}
```

If your producer supports *an explicit back-pressure signal* (like functional reactive streams), then you should use a special adapter to properly transfer their back-pressure signal to/from coroutines. The `kotlinx.coroutines` library has a number of out-of-the-box integration modules with various reactive libraries for this purpose. See [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/reactive/README.md).

**Note:** you **should not** mark your `foo` function with `suspend` modifier. Invocation of `foo` does not suspend invoker in anyway. It just immediately (synchronously) starts a producer coroutine.

To learn more about coroutines and different kinds of channels I highly recommend to study [the guide on kotlinx.coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md).

Comment: Thanks for exhaustive answer :)

Comment: First solution: At the point I get to the listener invocation, the channel has already been closed, without me closing it anywhere. "Channel was closed". Can you help me to understand why?

Comment: I created a question for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56257990/producetype-vs-channeltype