# produce<Type> vs Channel<Type>()

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx.coroutines.channels

Trying to understand channels. I want to channelify the android BluetoothLeScanner. Why does this work:

```
fun startScan(filters: List<ScanFilter>, settings: ScanSettings = defaultSettings): ReceiveChannel<ScanResult?> {
    val channel = Channel<ScanResult>()
    scanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
        override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult) {
            channel.offer(result)
        }
    }
    scanner.startScan(filters, settings, scanCallback)

    return channel
}
```

But not this:

```
fun startScan(scope: CoroutineScope, filters: List<ScanFilter>, settings: ScanSettings = defaultSettings): ReceiveChannel<ScanResult?> = scope.produce {
    scanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
        override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult) {
            offer(result)
        }
    }
    scanner.startScan(filters, settings, scanCallback)
}
```

It tells me `Channel was closed` when it wants to call `offer` for the first time.

**EDIT1:** According to the docs: `The channel is closed when the coroutine completes.` which makes sense. I know we can use `suspendCoroutine` with `resume` for a one shot `callback`-replacement. This however is a listener/stream-situation. I don't want the coroutine to complete

Comment: Make sure your coroutine scope's lifecycle matches the scope of the Bluetooth scanner. If you have an activity-bound scope and that doesn't fit, create a different one.

Comment: I played with scopes, no difference. I guess the problem is that produce returns after scanner.startscan, which means it's completed

Comment: The `produce` call returns immediately, and the value it returns is the `ReceiveChannel` you need to consume the data from. But yes, the `produce` block is supposed to be an infinite loop that pushes the data into the channel. In your case the `produce` block completes right away. So your first example is a better match to your callback-based approach.

Comment: `produce` is not what you want in this scenario. For a use case like this, you want to have a proper channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `produce`, you introduce scope to your Channel. This means, the code that produces the items, that are streamed over the channel, can be cancelled.

This also means that the lifetime of your Channel starts at the start of the lambda of the `produce` and ends when this lambda ends.

In your example, the lambda of your `produce` call almost ends immediately, which means your Channel is closed almost immediately.

Change your code to something like this:

```
fun CoroutineScope.startScan(filters: List<ScanFilter>, settings: ScanSettings = defaultSettings): ReceiveChannel<ScanResult?> = produce {
    scanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
        override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult) {
            offer(result)
        }
    }
    scanner.startScan(filters, settings, scanCallback)

    // now suspend this lambda forever (until its scope is canceled)
    suspendCancellableCoroutine<Nothing> { cont ->
        cont.invokeOnCancellation {
            scanner.stopScan(...)
        }
    }
}

...
val channel = scope.startScan(filter)
...
...
scope.cancel() // cancels the channel and stops the scanner.
```

I added the line `suspendCancellableCoroutine<Nothing> { ... }` to make it suspend 'forever'.

Update: Using `produce` and handling errors in a structured way (allows for Structured Concurrency):

```
fun CoroutineScope.startScan(filters: List<ScanFilter>, settings: ScanSettings = defaultSettings): ReceiveChannel<ScanResult?> = produce {
    // Suspend this lambda forever (until its scope is canceled)
    suspendCancellableCoroutine<Nothing> { cont ->
        val scanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
            override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult) {
                offer(result)
            }
            override fun onScanFailed(errorCode: Int) {
                cont.resumeWithException(MyScanException(errorCode))
            }
        }
        scanner.startScan(filters, settings, scanCallback)

        cont.invokeOnCancellation {
            scanner.stopScan(...)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, while this seems like the solution for "how to keep the coroutine given by the produce block alive", I think Marko and gMale are right and produce simply is not the right tool for this situation. Have an upvote still!

Comment: I think using `produce` is a good way to go. You can also handle errors in a structured way using produce. I update my answer above to show an example with handling errors in a structured way.